# Loading many to many data into viewmodel in mvc entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, many-to-many

View Model

```
public class ItemDetail
{
    public IEnumerable<DescriptionTag> DescrptionsTags { get; set; } //many to many join table
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        ItemDetail viewModel=new ItemDetail();

        viewModel.Items = db.Items.Include(i=>i.DescriptionTags); //eager loading related data

        if (id != null)
        {
            viewModel.DescrptionsTags = viewModel.Items.Where(i => i.ID == id.Value).Single().DescriptionTags; // loads the description tags to viewmodel property
        }


        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

View

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items) {

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.ID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @*Loading tags in the table*@
        @if (Model.DescrptionsTags != null)
        {
            foreach (var tag in item.DescriptionTags)
            {
                <a>@tag.Description.DescriptionName</a>
            }
        }
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Size)
    </td>  
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { id=item.ID}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Details:

The code works fine. The problem is, the tags do not get loaded into table until the user clicks the select link or when the page is loaded for the first time. Which is, the table gets loaded with tags only when an id is passed to the controller. That is not how I want it to behave. Is there a way I can load the tags without needing to pass the id?

What I am trying to do is similar to the tags in Stackoverflow. Each post has many tags and each tags can have many posts. What I need is, in a table column I want to load all the tags that relate to the particular item id of the row.

I am currently following a tutorial from this link - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application .
But the above code is my own version based on the tutorial. So, there might be a completely different way of doing what I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I know what you are trying to do but you don't need the conditional to load the Tags on your controller. It would be useful to see your items model as I guess it should include a navigation property DescriptionTags. Have you tried this?:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? id)
 {
        ItemDetail viewModel=new ItemDetail();

        viewModel.Items = db.Items.Include(i=>i.DescriptionTags); //eager loading
        related data


    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I do not load the tags then the tags wont be loaded to my view model property-'DescriptionTags'.

Comment: Your answer wont load the Description names in view model property-'DescriptionTags'. What I am trying to do is similar to the tags in Stackoverflow. Each post has many tags and each tags can have many posts. What I need is, in a table cell I want to load all the tags that relate to the particular item id. I am trying to do this by 'viewModel.DescrptionsTags = viewModel.Items.Where(i => i.ID == id.Value).Single().DescriptionTags;'. But for this to work, controller parameter needs to be passed. Since, at first load the parameter is not passed the tags column is blank.

Comment: Sorry, I am still lost, you want to load all the tags related to all your articles on a separate table? Obviously if you have if (id != null) before loading the tags they are not going to appear if you don;t have and id...

Could you include a mockup layout of what you want?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually what I wanted was to load the tags even when there is no id. For example, there is no id when the page first loads as no arguments will be passed to the controller. However, I figured it out. I used a foreach on viewmodel. You can check my answer. Maybe you will understand what I was trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

Solved. A foreach loop in the controller did the job.

```
ItemDetail viewModel=new ItemDetail();
viewModel.Items = db.Items.Include(i=>i.DescriptionTags);

foreach(Item i in viewModel.Items)
{
    viewModel.DescrptionsTags = i.DescriptionTags;
}
```